# How to always uncolapse tags in firefox inspector?

Tags: html, tags, firefox-developer-tools

i want tags to always be uncolapsed when i a refresh page. Is there an option or am i blind?

I tried:
use google and find an option to uncolapse tags by default

PS: <>, i have to enter more words to be able to ask this question.

Comment: What tags? ... in the inspector tab? If so, not sure there is an option to have that capability. You can, however, right-click the `<html` tag and choose the `Expand All` to expand everything, but it has to be done after each page load.

Comment: Yes, expand all so it is set by default. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do exactly what you're asking, but if you put an XPath expression like `/html/body/div/p[1]` into the search field at the top of the inspector, Firefox will highlight that element, and re-highlight it when you reload the page, expanding parent nodes as needed:

[image: A screenshot of the inspector with an XPath query]

To get an XPath to a node, you can right-click it, then Copy, then XPath.

You can also Alt+click the little triangular twisties to recursively expand nodes.